# using openlayers 3 and three.js to use openlayers 3 map as texture

Tags: three.js, gis, openlayers-3, texture-mapping

I am trying to use Openlayers 3 along with three.js to use openlayers output map as texture. I found that openlayers 3 is webgl based and so is three.js. So they must be compatible.

What I have done is displayed a map using ol.js function ol.Map().Now i want the map to be used as a texture in a terrain.

I think if i get the map as an image file instead of displaying in div container. The problem would be solved. But am unable to do it.

I have a terrain and a map but unable to use the map as texture for the terrain.

Can anybody help me with this. I am stuck and with no idea of what to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "terrain"?

Comment: by terrain i mean a land like 3d model

Comment: I have no idea what your map and image formats look like, but OpenLayers 3 has "blend modes" that you can apply to layers and make them "shine through" in different ways

Answer (score 0):

i am working on it, and i found a way.
i bind ol canvas to the css3d , and bind to the scene.
then it will works well.

and then you work just the coordinates, and the scale
i suggest ol and three.js will be the same scale and same coordinate.

but there will be another question, css3d and background z-index not work.
continuous resolution, when i found some way i will share it.